# Saving small sub-dataframes containing all values associated to a specific 'key'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd need a little suggestion on a procedure using pandas, I have a 2-columns dataset that looks like this:

```
A      0.4533
B      0.2323
A      1.2343
A      1.2353
B      4.3521
C      3.2113
C      2.1233
..      ...
```

where first column contains strings and the second one floats. Looking at each subgroup given by the 'keys' `'A','B','C'`, I would like to filter out the values in each subgroup that differ more than 20% from the minimum of each subgroup.
What I've tried to do has been:

```
out = df[df.groupby(stringcol)[floatcol].apply(lambda x: x <= x.min() * 1.2)]
```

But I'm **not sure** if, doing like this, the **global** minimum over the entire dataset is considered, or the minimum with respect to each subgroup, that is what I want.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: `x.min()` is the minimum among the group values.

Comment: thanks, is this a consequence of groupby operation?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "consequence", `groupby apply` applies a "function _func_ group-wise". This specifically what this operation is for.

Comment: Ok, I was just perplexed about the .apply part if it was applied groupwise or not. Now it is clear, thanks